# set unique fullname - django - integrityError - how to solve this?

Tags: python, django

I have a `uniqname` field in my user profile model. The logic is: if new user's name is `john` and if there is other john in db, the new john should get the name `john1`. if 2 johns in db, new john should get `john3`.

i tried to achieve this with this code:

```
def set_uniqname(userprofile, fullname, i=0):
   new_uniqname = u"{}{}".format(fullname, str(i) if i else '')
   try:
       userprofile.uniqname = new_uniqname
       userprofile.save()
       return userprofile
   except IntegrityError:
       i += 1
       return set_uniqname(userprofile, fullname, i)

name = request.POST.get('name').title()
email = request.POST.get('email')
passwort = request.POST.get('passwort')

""" create base django user with random username """
random_username = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 26))
new_user = User.objects.create_user(random_username, email, passwort)

""" update the created userprofile with unique fullname for URL """
userprofile = new_user.get_profile()


uniqname = name.replace(' ','')
userprofile = set_uniqname(userprofile, uniqname)
```

But i am getting error:

```
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

the uniqname field in user profile is defined in this way:

```
uniqname = models.TextField(unique=True, default=None, null=True)
```

i am setting this field to `None` in post_save signal, so that i can set this to uniqname in my create_account method:

```
def create_profile(sender, **kw):
  user = kw["instance"]
  if kw["created"]:
      up = Person(user=user) 
      up.uniqname = None
      up.save()        
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

any ideas why i am getting this error and how i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your database threw an `IntegrityError` and you don't handle the exception on a database level. You have to rollback the current transaction to a point without an error. As you probably don't want to rollback to the start of the transaction that encapsulates the whole view, you'd want to run the code in an `atomic` block. Then you'll be able to rollback just this particular statement:

```
from django.db import transaction

def set_uniqname(userprofile, fullname, i=0):
   new_uniqname = u"{}{}".format(fullname, str(i) if i else '')
   try:
       with transaction.atomic():
           userprofile.uniqname = new_uniqname
           userprofile.save()
           return userprofile
   except IntegrityError:
       i += 1
       return set_uniqname(userprofile, fullname, i)
```

[`atomic()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) will automatically create a savepoint at the start of the block, and when the block is successful, commit it to the database. If an error is thrown, the block is rolled back to the savepoint and the error is allowed to propagate upwards to your `try` block.

Comment: i am using django 1.4 :( ``atomic`` is only from 1.6 onwards, right?

Comment: @doniyor You're right. In 1.4 you can use `transaction.commit_on_success()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can override save() method from 'YourModel'. Here is example of my idea.

```
def _get_unique_name(self, name, count=0):
    """
    Method returns unique name.
    """
    try:
        name = YourModel.objects.get(name=name)
        count = count + 1
        name = "%s%s" % (name, count)
        self._get_unique_name(name, count) #recursion 
    except:
        return name


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Overides save method from YourModel.
    """
    self.name = self._get_unique_name(self.name)
    super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You have to try this.. maybe there is some bugs. I didn't test it. It's directly from my head :)

You should do this in your Model Class.